# unable to display a tooltip on the bundle layout

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js, tooltip, bundle-layout

I'm trying to reproduce this (bundle layout): http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/7607999 and it's fine.

[image]

However, I'd like to add a tooltip on each link when I hover a node (the tooltip would explain why items are linked together). I have absolutely no clue how to do this. I've tried all sorts of codes, but as I don't really understand it, it's tough. Any idea?

I'd like the tooltip to be shown either on each link (say, in middle) (but I'm afraid that the tooltips related to the highlighted links will not be much visible/legible), or either to aggregate the text of each tooltip highlighted links in a div put somewhere below the graph.

Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>

.node {
  font: 300 11px "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  fill: #bbb;
}

.node:hover {
  fill: #000;
}

.link {
  stroke: steelblue;
  stroke-opacity: .4;
  fill: none;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.node:hover,
.node--source,
.node--target {
  font-weight: 700;
}

.node--source {
  fill: #2ca02c;
}

.node--target {
  fill: #d62728;
}

.link--source,
.link--target {
  stroke-opacity: 1;
  stroke-width: 2px;
}

.link--source {
  stroke: #d62728;
}

.link--target {
  stroke: #2ca02c;
}
/* test_tooltip addition 
div.tooltip {   
  position: absolute;           
  text-align: center;           
  width: 60px;                  
  height: 28px;                 
  padding: 2px;             
  font: 12px sans-serif;        
  background: lightsteelblue;   
  border: 0px;      
  border-radius: 8px;           
  pointer-events: none;         
}
*/
</style>
<body>
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<div>
<script>

// test_tooltip addition
var tooltip = d3.select("body")
    .append("div")
    .attr("class", "tooltip")
  .attr("x", 200)
  .attr("y", 200)
  .attr("width", 400)
  .attr("height", 100)
  .attr("fill", "aliceblue")
    .style("position", "absolute")
    .style("z-index", "10")
    .style("opacity", 0)
    //.style("visibility", "hidden")
    .text("a simple tooltip");
// end of addition

var diameter = 480, // diameter = 960 ou 480
    radius = diameter / 2,
    innerRadius = radius - 120;

var cluster = d3.layout.cluster()
    .size([360, innerRadius])
    .sort(null)
    .value(function(d) { return d.size; });

var bundle = d3.layout.bundle();

var line = d3.svg.line.radial()
    .interpolate("bundle")
    .tension(.85)
    .radius(function(d) { return -d.y; })
    .angle(function(d) { return d.x / 180 * Math.PI; });

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", diameter)
    .attr("height", diameter)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + radius + "," + radius + ")");

var link = svg.append("g").selectAll(".link"),
    node = svg.append("g").selectAll(".node");

d3.json("test.json", function(error, classes) {
  var nodes = cluster.nodes(packageHierarchy(classes)),
      links = packageLinks(nodes); // links = packageImports(nodes);

  link = link
      .data(bundle(links))
    .enter().append("path")
      .each(function(d) { d.source = d[0], d.target = d[d.length - 1]; })
      .attr("class", "link")
      .attr("d", line); 
      // .attr("d", line); //original
      /*
      // test_tooltip addition
      .attr("d", line)
      .on("mouseover", function(d) {
          div.transition()      
              .duration(200)        
              .style("opacity", .9);        
          div   .html(d.RG)
              .style("left", (d3.event.pageX) + "px")       
              .style("top", (d3.event.pageY - 28) + "px");  
          })        
      .on("mouseout", function(d) {     
          div.transition()      
              .duration(500)        
              .style("opacity", 0); 
      });
      // test_tooltip addition
      */

  node = node
      .data(nodes.filter(function(n) { return !n.children; }))
  // skip if URL not desired
    .enter().append('a')
    .attr("xlink:href", function(d){return d.url;})
    .append("text")
  // skip until there
  //  .enter().append("text")
      .attr("class", "node")
      .attr("dy", ".31em")
      // put the parents on the left rather than on the right
      .attr("transform", function(d) { return "rotate(" + (d.x - 90) + ")translate(" + ((-d.y) - 8) + ",0)" + (d.x < 180 ? "" : "rotate(180)"); })
      //.attr("transform", function(d) { return "rotate(" + (d.x - 90) + ")translate(" + (d.y + 8) + ",0)" + (d.x < 180 ? "" : "rotate(180)"); })
      .style("text-anchor", function(d) { return d.x < 180 ? "end" : "start"; })
      .text(function(d) { return d.key /*+ " truc"; */})
      .on("mouseover", mouseovered)
      .on("mouseout", mouseouted);
});

function mouseovered(d) {
  node
      .each(function(n) { n.target = n.source = false; });

  link
      .classed("link--target", function(l) { if (l.target === d) return l.source.source = true; })
      .classed("link--source", function(l) { if (l.source === d) return l.target.target = true; })
    .filter(function(l) { return l.target === d || l.source === d; })
      .each(function() { this.parentNode.appendChild(this); });

  node
      .classed("node--target", function(n) { return n.target; })
      .classed("node--source", function(n) { return n.source; });
}

function mouseouted(d) {
  link
      .classed("link--target", false)
      .classed("link--source", false);

  node
      .classed("node--target", false)
      .classed("node--source", false);
}

d3.select(self.frameElement).style("height", diameter + "px");

// Lazily construct the package hierarchy from class names.
function packageHierarchy(classes) {
  var map = {};

  function find(name, data) {
    var node = map[name], i;
    if (!node) {
      node = map[name] = data || {name: name, children: []};
      if (name.length) {
        node.parent = find(name.substring(0, i = name.lastIndexOf(".")));
        node.parent.children.push(node);
        node.key = name.substring(i + 1);
      }
    }
    return node;
  }

  classes.forEach(function(d) {
    find(d.name, d);
  });

  return map[""];
}

// Return a list of imports/links for the given array of nodes.
function packageLinks(nodes) { //function packageImports(nodes) {
  var map = {},
      links = []; // imports = [];

  // Compute a map from name to node.
  nodes.forEach(function(d) {
    map[d.name] = d;
  });

  // For each import/link, construct a link from the source to target node.
  nodes.forEach(function(d) {
    if (d.links) d.links.forEach(function(i) { //if (d.imports) d.imports.forEach(function(i) {
      links.push({source: map[d.name], target: map[i]}); //imports.push({source: map[d.name], target: map[i]});
    });
  });

  return links; //return imports;
}

/*
// test_tooltip addition
d3.select("body")
    .append("svg:circle")
    .attr("stroke", "black")
    .attr("fill", "aliceblue")
    .attr("r", 50)
    .attr("cx", 52)
    .attr("cy", 52)
    .on("mouseover", function(){return tooltip.style("visibility", "visible");})
    .on("mousemove", function(){return tooltip.style("top", (event.pageY-10)+"px").style("left",(event.pageX+10)+"px");})
    .on("mouseout", function(){return tooltip.style("visibility", "hidden");});
// test_tooltip addition
*/
</script>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code for tool-tip will comes on second place ... first you have to check that at-least your link handle the mouse event or not

defiantly not why ?

because of this part in css

```
.link {
  stroke: steelblue;
  stroke-opacity: .4;
  fill: none;
  pointer-events: none;    <====
}
```

remove pointer events line and than check your tool-tip code of mouseover/mouseout event it will work ...

**FYI:**
there is reason why in bundle layout has pointer-events set to none ...
because there will be one circle in middle that handle drag and it will allow to rotate this diagram ... if you remove "pointer-events:none " than your events on links start listen and it will mess with drag event of that middle circle ..

so  be careful with this "pointer-events:none" if you don't have that rotational functionality than it's OK but you need both at a same time.. you need to manage that with some other option like provide button that will set "pointer-events:none" for while  when you rotate and once rotation done again remove that pointer-events:node or apply pointer-events:all so you link tool-tip will work ..

Hope this helps

Comment: Hello and thank you for your answer. I have removed the pointer-events line, but nothing has changed. I can't rotate the diagram (couldn't find where to drag), and anyway I don't care/wish to. So, I'm still stuck with my tooltip that does not show. I guess I did something wrong? Although I barely touched the original code.

Comment: look at the elements in svg , is there any circle or path that on top of links nodes... and also try to bind mouse-over and mouse-out event if you can listen them on your link than you can hide and show tool-tip manually on this two functions